# Cannot load a certain assembly due to version conflict

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, configuration, serilog

One assembly (exe) depends on a nuget package (actually serilog.settings.configuration 3.1.0)
This package depends on microsoft.extensions.options.configurationextensions (>=2.0.0) which in turn depends on microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder (>= 2.0.0)
All this is ok.

However I have other projects (class libraries) in the solutions which are not referred to from the exe project (to be loaded at runtime) and one of these depends on a newer version of microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder (6.0.0) all is not ok.
The new version cannot be loaded because the exe project has already loaded the old one.

I can solve this problem by explicitly add microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder (6.0.0) as dependency for the exe project, but I guess there is a better way to do this, is it?
(If the dynamically loaded assembly which depends on the newer version for some reason e.g. users choice, is not loaded I will end up with unnecessary new assembly loaded in the process, perhaps not a big problem in this case, but could be in other cases).

I am using .Net 6 so loading into separate AppDomain is (afaik) not an option

Answer (score 0):

If those assemblies are strongly named, putting different versions of those into GAC with gacutil.exe should do the trick. If that does not work for you, you still have the option to override the default loading behavior.
The following two articles explain the topic very well (for NET Framework):

- [Understanding How Assemblies Load in C# .NET](https://michaelscodingspot.com/assemblies-load-in-dotnet/)
- [How to resolve .NET reference and NuGet package version conflicts](https://michaelscodingspot.com/how-to-resolve-net-reference-and-nuget-package-version-conflicts/)

If AppDomain and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve is not an option for you, then try using [System.Runtime.Loader Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader?view=net-5.0), specifically [AssemblyDependencyResolver class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblydependencyresolver?view=net-5.0).

Comment: Thanks
I forgot to tell that I am using Prism 8 with DirectoryModuleCatalog which throws when initializing the module with the mentioned Binder dependency.
Cannot tweak like you mentioned (unless exploiting open source)